# Decoding an array

Tags: c, arrays, unix, encryption

So, I'm trying to decode this array into a string of text (ASCII)
I'm not entirely sure how to go about this and I have no experience with C, but I do have access to a text editor or a terminal. Is there any tools i can use on a UNIX-based platform (GNU)?

```
char name[] = { 0x64, 0160, (114-63), (064+03), 0x00 };
```

Thank you!

Comment: they're just character codes. `{ hex, octal, decimal, octal, hex }`. look up the ascii codes taht correspond to the values.

Comment: @MarcB +1. I've got an ascii table taped to my wall because of that.

Comment: Also `man ascii` helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, the easiest way would be to compile and run the program. But, that's not really the point of this kind of code exercise. Once you recognize the *trick* that these are just different base representations of numbers, then you real should go through the task of calculating the numbers and looking them up in the ascii table that's almost certainly in the back of the textbook or available on the same tutorial site.

Remember the fundamental theorem of arithmetic:

```
12345 = 1 *10^4 + 2 *10^3 + 3 * 10^2 + 4 * 10^1 + 5 * 10^0
0xABC = A * 16^2 + B * 16^1 + C * 16^0
```

---

You can also investigate these with a (sufficiently powerful) text editor. You'll need to do the addition yourself, but in `vim` you hit ctrl-V and then the number followed by whitespace (which you can then delete).

Answer (score 0):

If you'll print this sequence using `printf("%c",name[i])` in a loop for each index of name, it will automatically convert hexadecimal and octal representations to decimal and print associated ASCII symbol

Comment: You are missing the fact that one of the values, for example, is greater than 127, so it becomes codepage dependent, and is not necessarily portable.

Comment: Code validation is not part of problem, it will lead to broader argument whether code shall be checked before transmission or checked after reception, which also depends on type of channel and BW of channel used.

Comment: How does bandwidth and channel type remotely affect the code? That would be a different level of the OSI stack, and is irrelevant to encoding at this level.

Comment: I am referring to any change in code during transmission, which depends on channel type and BW. Yeah it is irrelevant at this level, this is why I did not discuss it here. One thing to consider is no standard code structure or limits are discussed here.

Comment: @Dogbert Which value is > 127 in `0x64, 0160, (114-63), (064+03), 0x00 `?  Or are you addressing generalities?

Comment: @chux IIRC `0160` gets interpreted as `0x160` ==> `352` in decimal, and on my system, it gets printed out as `112` via `printf("%d");`. Also, I'm addressing general cases.

Comment: @Dogbert Hmmmm.  I expected `0160` to get interpreted as an _octal_ constant per C11 6.4.4.1 1 "octal-constant:", as it begins with a `0`, with the decimal equivalent value of `112`.  My gcc seems to agree.

Comment: @Dogbert, the value 0160 is an octal value, not hex value and becomes: 0xB0.  Any printable value would depend on the code page, however, going over a bus to a device, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If the integral values correspond to ascii you could simply cast them to characters. Characters are actually `uint8` in C. So if you have integers that correspond to some ascii you can simply the compiler to treat them as such.